# Why is google developers tool giving me an error if I already refractored com.example?

Tags: android

I had an error while uploading the APP to google developers console as I created the packages as com.example. ...

While trying to upload it to google play, this error comes up

SPANISH: "Debes utilizar otro nombre de paquete porque "com.example" está restringido."

ENGLISH: "You need to choose a different package name because "com.example is already chosen."

[image: manifest]

[image]

Do you know what may be causing this issue?

Thanks,
Marc

Comment: Try clean/rebuild then remake the signed APK

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to change com.example.app to com.minigolf.app, then
1)In your Project pane, click on the little gear icon ( Gears icon )
2)Uncheck / De-select the Compact Empty Middle Packages option

[image]

3)Your package directory will now be broken up in individual directories
4)Individually select each directory you want to rename, and

1. Right-click it
2. Select Refactor
3. Click on Rename
4. In the Pop-up dialog, click on Rename Package instead of Rename Directory
5. Enter the new name and hit Refactor
6. Allow a minute to let Android Studio update all changes
   7.Note: When renaming com in Android Studio, it might give a warning. In such case, select Rename All

[image]

5)Now open your Gradle Build File (build.gradle - Usually app or mobile). Update the applicationId to your new Package Name and Sync Gradle, if it hasn't already been updated automatically:

[image]
6)Done! Anyways, Android Studio needs to make this process a little simpler.